# What is the contour lines of $\frac{x-y}{x^2+y^2}$?

Tags: calculus, functions

What is the contour lines of $\frac{x-y}{x^2+y^2}$?
I know hot they looks like but I have to describe them...(via $c$, i.e. $c=\frac{x-y}{x^2+y^2}$).

I glad if you will help me with this...

The result is:$$\left(\sqrt c\cdot x-\frac1{2\sqrt c}\right)^2 - \frac1{4c}+\left(\sqrt c\cdot y+\frac1{2\sqrt c}\right)^2 - \frac1{4c}=0$$
so:
$$\left(\sqrt c\cdot x-\frac1{2\sqrt c}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt c\cdot y+\frac1{2\sqrt c}\right)^2=\frac1{2c}$$
??
Thank you!

Comment: Notice the level lines $c=\frac{x-y}{x^+y^2}$, or $cx^2+cy^2-x+y=0$ are quadratic equations. Therefore the lines are conics (parabolas, elipses, hyperbolas, ...). We just need to determine which. For this you could 'complete the squares' and then you will see the typical equations of these conic models. (alternatively you could use the discriminant to classify).

Comment: @ABC, can you help me with the 'complete the squares'?? I know about it but I don't know how to use it here...

Comment: $cx^2-x=c(x^2-\frac{1}{c}x)=c(x^2-\frac{1}{c}x+\frac{1}{4c^2})-\frac{1}{4c}=c(x-\frac{1}{2c})^2-\frac{1}{4c}$. It is like you imagine the coefficient of the $x$ term is the $2b$ in $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ba+b^2$. Then you need to add and subtract what would be the $b^2$. Do the same for the part $cy^2+y$. You will get an equation for the form $c(x-A)^2+c(y-B)^2+C=0$, where $A,B,C$ are new constants that you need to determine and that depend on $c$. So, it looks like they are going to be translated circles most of the time.

Comment: You can take all those $$

Comment: So what I got is correct? and is this form? Circles?

Comment: It is kind of right. We shouldn't take the square root of $c$ if we don't know it is positive. Better take it out of the squares. It is circles most of the time, but a case-by-case study should be done for the different values of $c$. For example, if $c=0$ the the equation from the beginning would have been $x-y=0$, which is a line (there wouldn't be squares to complete).

Comment: But at the function $x\ne 0, y\ne 0$...

Comment: You have points $x=y\neq0$, for which the function equals to zero. So, the level line for $c=0$ is a line $y=x$, minus the point $(0,0)$, which is not in the domain.